# Call another function inside javascript namespace

Tags: javascript

I've something like this:

**edited**:

I have conflicted socket.io files:

```
<script src="https://muazkhan.com:9001/dist/RTCMultiConnection.js"></script>
<script src="https://muazkhan.com:9001/node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js"></script>
<script src="https://muazkhan.com:9001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://stream.ciak.live/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This is part of my code and integrated with solutions from other members, like below:

```
<script>
function loadScript(url, namespace, clbk) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.dataset.namespace = namespace;

    if (clbk) {
      script.onload = () => clbk(window[namespace]);
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

 loadScript('https://muazkhan.com:9001/socket.io/socket.io.js', 'socketIO1', (socketIO1) => {
    var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
    connection.socketURL = 'https://muazkhan.com:9001/';
    connection.socketMessageEvent = 'ciak-liveshow';

connection.onstream = function(event) {
    if (event.extra.roomOwner === true) {
    if (connection.extra.broadcastuser>1){
        $("#broadcast-viewers-counter").html('Online viewers: <b>' + connection.extra.broadcastuser + ' Users</b>');
    }else{
        $("#broadcast-viewers-counter").html('Online viewers: <b>' + connection.extra.broadcastuser + ' User</b>');
    }
    
    event.mediaElement.controls = false;
    var video = document.getElementById('main-video');
    video.setAttribute('data-streamid', event.streamid);

    // video.style.display = 'none';
    if(event.type === 'local') {
        video.muted = true;
        video.volume = 0;
    }
    video.srcObject = event.stream;
    requestMedia(event.stream); <-- this called from LoadScript SocketIO2
    $('#main-video').show();
    } 
};
  });

  loadScript('https://stream.ciak.live/socket.io.js', 'socketIO2', (socketIO2) => {
function connect_server(){
    var socketOptions = {secure: true, reconnection: true, reconnectionDelay: 1000, timeout:15000, pingTimeout: 15000, pingInterval: 45000, "force new connection":true, query: {framespersecond: framerate, audioBitrate: audiobitrate}};

    //start socket connection
    rtmpsocket = io.connect(socketio_address.value, socketOptions);
    rtmpsocket.on('connect_timeout', (timeout) => {
        console.log("state on connection timeout= " +timeout);
        output_message.innerHTML="Connection timed out";
        recordingCircle.style.fill='gray';
        
    });
}

function requestMedia(Stream){
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(250);
}
  });
</script>
```

But the problem is, when I called requestMedia() from the first socketIO1, but requestMedia() was undefined when it was called from socketIO1.

```
https://muazkhan.com:9001/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

is perform broadcast stream using rtcmulticonnection package and

```
https://stream.ciak.live/socket.io.js
```

is used for live stream to facebook/youtube platform from browserlivestream package

my goal is combine 2 of this socket.io

**Updated Solution**

I research this two library and found that socket.io from browserlivestream is to old. The version is 1.7.4 and socket.io from rtcmulticonnection is 4.4.1. After upgrading socket.io browserlivestream, I can use same socket.io

Comment: When I google "javascript namespace" the only thing I can find is related to TypeScript, not regular JavaScript. What makes you think adding `script.dataset.namespace` will create a global variable `window[namespace]`?

Comment: I got those script from another member suggestion. He said - Basicly from this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespacing-in-javascript/,

Comment: That describes using objects to implement the Module design pattern. It has nothing to do with adding `data-namespace` to a `<script>` element.

Comment: What is the code in those scripts you are loading?

Comment: Inside first socket is broadcast video using rtc multiconnection library and the 2nd one is perform live streaming to other platform. But there's a function inside 2nd load and called by first one

Comment: No I mean can you please post the overall structure (module pattern etc) and in particular the part that interacts with `window[namespace]` of the code in those script files?

Comment: I've edited my question and give more detail from part of my code, and the goal is combine 2 socket.io file, because it part of different library

Comment: It's still not clear what *socket.io.js* is and what it has to do with the `data-namespace`  attribute you're setting on its script element

Comment: First socket.io is part of library for making broadcast video, each user will join a room to see broadcast video using webrtc. The second socket.io is use for send video stream from broadcast video to server gateway rtmp and sending video to youtube/facebook rtmp. For data-namespace I don't know what for, I just implemented from other member stackoverflow solution

Comment: Then it's probably useless here. Please link the answer where you got this from so we can confirm.

Comment: This is the answer from other member https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291930/combine-2-files-socket-io

Comment: @cloudrider Looks like the answer to your previous question doesn't actually work. You shouldn't have accepted it if it didn't solve your problem

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for your information. I already revert my accept and he already delete their comment. Do you have a clue for this problem? Very confusing about this

Comment: So what is the actual problem there? why do you need to use two *socket.io.js* scripts? Are they different versions of the same library or what?

Comment: Socket.io from muazkhan is different with socket.io from socket.io ciak.live. the function is diferrent. Library muazkhan is using for broadcast video (rtcmulticonnection library) and ciak.live (browserlivestream) is for communicate rtmp gateway. Ciak.live is under my control but muazkhan not under my control. So I can't modify script on muazkhan

Comment: Yes, but different why? Can't you just use the Socket.IO v4.4.1 that you're loading from https://muazkhan.com:9001/socket.io/socket.io.js for your own purposes? If no, you will at least need to fix your script hosted at ciak.live to not override the global `io` variable. Are you building this yourself? If no, where did you get it from? If yes, please show us your webpack config.

Comment: No, already try socket io muazkhan for gateway rtmp. It doesn't work and vice versa. Script socket.io ciak from this git https://github.com/apivideo/browserLiveStream. I want combine muazkhan library and that git library

Comment: I think, I know the problem why it's doesn't work and need two different socket. Because different socket.io server version is 1.7.4 and the client is using 4.7.2. Since on muaz already is using version 4. I'm trying to upgrade socket.io server version to 4.